# How to access a Grid within a data template in my View code

Tags: wpf

I have some XAML like this

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Plugins}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CurrentProductIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                >

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="PluginRegion">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I need to access the Grid called "PluginRegion" in my procedural code ( the objective is to add children at run time to this grid).
How can I access this Grid since there is no member being created.

Comment: That’s not how it works. You add items to your ItemsSource (`Plugins`-Collections in your case) and the `DataTemplate` defines how this Item is displayed.

Comment: Yeah I sort of figured.  
So I guess my question how DO I define a tab control where I can programatically add content to the tab control and let the template figure out how to display it 
Or rather how do I sort of bind something in the collection to the Row in the grid. I am probably asking this very wrongly :-(

Comment: Do a little more research about Templating in WPF and you will find the answer on your own.  
I can’t think of a scenario where accessing a control inside of a template is a good solution.